# Traffic from domain to sub-domain

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, traffic

We have a listing on domain x.com which has links to subdomain.x.com

Analytics settings Referral Exclusion List has domain x.com and subdomain.x.com.

AFAIK, this means that view under this same account shouldn't have referrals neither from x.com or subdomain.x.com. Also the session should stay the same.

Now the problem is that I cannot see traffic between these URLs. Is possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter to the view to include the hostname: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en

Another option is for you to create multiple views to only include a certain hostname. In your case, one view to include only traffic with hostname subdomain.x.com and another to include only x.com.